# Is there a good, simple, free RAD tool for web development?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, web

I need to develop a basic web application that will allow data entry into a SQL Server database, with basic security. I work in education and budgets are (very) limited.

It's a very long time since I've developed anything at all. Is there a good, free RAD/GUI tool out there that can potentially create this very quickly? I'm fine to tweak the code but frankly would rather that 99% of the work was done for me. To give an example, the last good tool I used that could do this was IronSpeed, but this is rather expensive.

Thanks,
 Gavin

Comment: VS Community and SQL SERVER Express are free tool to build web except that lot of free tool to build very extensive web application just search on internet we don't need to buy anything :) except hosting

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Ok, I understand the mark down - what I would say is that it is harder to describe the problem / what has been done to solve it when what I am really looking for is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:
MVC , Razor.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx

Visual Studio Community 2013
November 12, 2014

Visual Studio Community 2013 is a new edition that enables you to unleash the full power of Visual Studio to develop cross-platform solutions. Create apps in one unified IDE. Get Visual Studio extensions that incorporate new languages, features, and development tools into this IDE. (These extensions are available from the Visual Studio Gallery.) Find out more details about Visual Studio Community 2013 here.

Download Visual Studio Community 2013.
What's in Visual Studio Community 2013

```
Professional-grade editing, code analysis, and debugging support
Support for open-source workflows (Git)
Compilers for managed languages, C++ and more
Cross-platform mobile development for your preferred device and platform, including the web, Android, iOS, and Windows Phone with the free Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova extension
Take advantage of cloud services with simplified Azure SDK integration, and incorporate modern app analytics and telemetry with Application Insights
Access to all the Visual Studio 2013 extensions on the Visual Studio Gallery
Visual Studio Community 2013 includes Update 4, which is a cumulative update of all previous Visual Studio 2013 updates
```

APPEND:

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Looks like VS 2015 is communitified as well.